# Fetch more SELECT data based on input

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, optimization

Seems like a simple answer, but so far from what I've found, it might be not feasible using stored procedures.

Just wanted to ask though, as there might be an elegant solution....
(BTW: I am running my DB on an SQL Server 2014)

I have a very simple select

```
select companyID, companyName 
from tblCompanies
```

However in some cases, I need to fetch a bigger set of data

```
select companyID, companyName, companyAddress, companyCountry 
from tblCompanies
```

Of course this can be done by creating multiple stored procedures

- getCompaniesLite
- getCompaniesBasic
- getCompaniesFull etc

It is also possible to pass a parameter and choose among totally different SELECTS using IF-ELSE.

Both ways seem cumbersome though, with a lot of duplication and maintainability issues..

Perhaps there might be a way to fetch specific columns based on that input value, e.g. something like this:

```
select 
    companyID, companyName, 
    case when @FULL = 1 then companyAddress end 
from tblCompanies
```

Comment: Seems like the granularity of your stored procs might be wrong, if all you are doing is returning a subset of a table's columns.

Answer (score 0):

If all you have to do is get the results in different columns as you explain in your example, perhaps the easiest way would be to simply generate as many views as necessary and not use procedures, but it depends a bit on the rest of the operations you need to do in your logic.

**CompaniesBasic_View**

```
SELECT companyID, companyName
FROM tblCompanies
```

**CompaniesLite_View** (non relative)

```
SELECT companyID, companyName, companyAddress
FROM tblCompanies
```

**CompaniesFull_View** (non relative)

```
SELECT companyID, companyName, companyAddress, companyCountry 
FROM tblCompanies
```

You could even generate each view relative to the previous one if you think that could make maintenance easier for you. This way, when you add new columns to your basic view, they will appear directly in their relative views. (Weigh the pros and cons of this option and watch out for performance depending on the complexity of your queries).

**CompaniesBasic_View**

```
SELECT companyID, companyName
FROM tblCompanies
```

**CompaniesLite_View** (relative)

```
SELECT cb.*, tblCompanies.companyAddress
FROM CompaniesBasic_View cb, tblCompanies
WHERE cb.companyID = tblCompanies.companyID
```

**CompaniesFull_View** (relative)

```
SELECT cl.*, tblCompanies.companyCountry
FROM CompaniesLite_View cl, tblCompanies
WHERE cl.companyID = tblCompanies.companyID
```

Later you could use these views within a stored procedure if at any time you need to perform more complex operations. To do this, it would be enough to pass the name of the view you need as an argument and execute it directly through EXEC.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DoSomethingWithCompanies] (
    @myView Varchar(50)
) AS
BEGIN
    SET @myQuery = 'SELECT * FROM ' + @myView ;
    EXEC @myQuery;

    -- Do things
END;
```

Comment: I believe this would lead to more of a nightmare maintenance.  Especially if queries are written and need to be optimized with joins and such.  Best probably to just grab the few extra columns and ignore them in production vs trying to maintain versions.  Also, passing a view variable to stores procedure and executing could be dangerous if not validated / qualified as a known legit view against the system tables.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to overthink this.  How much time would you be saving.  This sample of companies probably millisecond?  But  think bigger down-stream to rest of what your system does.  Do some timed queries at different times and record stats due to caching of data.  So one day do the abbreviated on realistic queries you would be calling, another day (or later same day), do with ALL columns.  How much do you really save.

In addition, get to your more complex / detailed / JOIN queries and do similar.  How much time do you save.

Now, think of the interface.  Just because you have 10 fields available and only want to show 2, easy enough for the user-interface to present only those.  But if user changes to detail view, you already have the data to show all 10 fields without having to go back to the database and query again, which you have no defeated the purpose of smaller set just to save a second or two.

From a maintenance perspective, I think what you are looking for by this is not worth the effort.

Now, if there are some tables that have confidential data, then yes, I would start with a non-confidential, full data query vs a FULL data WITH Confidential data, but those would be on a case-by-case requirement anyhow.